# Shortest path to leaf in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm using recursion to find the shortest path in a BST(Binary Search Tree) and the shortest path should be the first childless leaf that is found. Whenever I return it gives me back the root. I've tried many various ways and I either keep getting the root back for a nullPointerException. Here is what I have

```
     public int minPath(){
     if(isEmpty()){
         return -1;
     }
     else{
         return findMin(root);
     }
 }

 private int findMin(IntegerTreeNode tNode){
     if((tNode.left != null) && (tNode.right != null)){
         findMin(tNode.left);
         findMin(tNode.right);
     }
     return tNode.item;
 }
```

I think what is happening is that it is returning the start of the stack, so how would I return the first childless leaf node?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Breadth-First-Search to solve this issue, since it will find the shortest path to a specified destination with unweighted edges. Since this is a BST, there should be no weighted edges, so BFS would be your algorithm of choice here.

Here is a wonderful presentation and pseudocode follow up of the algorithm:

[BFS Tutorial](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/faculty/solis/cs210/2013/slides/NewBFS.pdf)

Your goal state will just be a node that doesn't have any children, hence a leaf node. Since BFS will find you the shortest path to this goal, this algorithm will return the first leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your `findMin` method returns an `int`, but you are making the recursive calls without using their returned `int`s at all! I'd advise you to redesign your method while thinking about how you can utilize your recursive calls' returned numbers.